# Office-js installation options

Tags: outlook, add-in, office-js

I have a vba outlook add-in that is all ready up and running but some users have trouble installing so I thought to develop a new add-in.

I want to develop an office add-in to run on all office platforms (most important are desktop platforms from 2010 and up)
And I found office-js but some organizations don't allow users access to the office store..

Is there another way to distribute an office-js add in? And is there a way to convert my vba add in to something else? Like a com add in? Is it still alive?
I really need help to find the best practices for this situation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish

Comment: Office js is no good if you need to support Office 2010 - it was only genrrally available in Office 2013 and the application-specific API's are only Office 2016 I think,

Comment: For Office 2010 there is no "all platforms" possibility. VBA can work for Windows and Mac, but not on-line or on mobile. (In any case Office 2010 doesn't work on those platforms.) Office JS is only really viable for Office 365 (especially Outlook) and it can be installed on a SharePoint server or in a local folder, besides being distributed via the Office Store. VSTO is an alternative to VBA, but only for Windows desktop.

Comment: Office.js add-ins can be sideloaded onto the Exchange account, without the store, but an Exchange server is necessary. However they are only supported in Outlook 2013, Outlook 2016, Outlook 365 desktop, OWA, Mac and Mobile. Each version only supports certain API sets (i.e. Outlook 2013 only supports up to 1.4), so depending on your requirements/necessary APIs, it may not be possible to get the functionality you need across the clients you need. As mentioned above there is no support for Outlook 2010 for Office.JS.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I mostly interested in desktop add-ins so how about COM addin? Is it still available? Were can I find a good tutorial about it? PS I'm running win 10..

Comment: You can start with the "Create your first VSTO add-in for Outlook" walkthrough. Here's the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2017